# get Permission Denial even when using <uses-permission> for SET_ALARM?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-permissions, android-alarms

I'm very new to Android Studio as well as android programming. I've just read about the first common Intent tutorial, it's about the `AlarmClock`. I tried writing a simple code to test that Intent but it's not working with a `SecurityException` thrown, the stack trace looks like this:

> 05-20 15:36:25.010 2342-2342/com.viphalong.helloandroid E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                             Process: com.viphalong.helloandroid, PID: 2342
>                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.viphalong.helloandroid/com.viphalong.helloandroid.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.SET_ALARM cmp=com.android.deskclock/.HandleApiCalls (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{ad271560 2342:com.viphalong.helloandroid/u0a52} (pid=2342, uid=10052) requires com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.SET_ALARM cmp=com.android.deskclock/.HandleApiCalls (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{ad271560 2342:com.viphalong.helloandroid/u0a52} (pid=2342, uid=10052) requires com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM
>                                                                                 at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2096)
>                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1419)
>                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
>                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:842)
>                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
>                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
>                                                                                 at com.viphalong.helloandroid.MainActivity.createAlarm(MainActivity.java:22)
>                                                                                 at com.viphalong.helloandroid.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
>                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
>                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Here is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            package="com.viphalong.helloandroid">
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
    <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:supportsRtl="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>

      </activity>
    </application>

   </manifest>
```

And here is the main code:

```
package com.viphalong.helloandroid;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.provider.AlarmClock;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //try creating a simple alarming
        createAlarm("Welldone", 0, 1);
    }
    void createAlarm(String msg, int hours, int minutes){
        Intent it = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
        it.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, msg)
          .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hours)
          .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, minutes);
        if(it.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
          startActivity(it);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I put the line

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
```

in the manifest file. But the exception is still thrown making me really confusing.

Comment: What is api level of Device in which you are testing?

Comment: @SurenderKumar the API level is 19

Comment: @Hopeless see my answer below.

Comment: Check this developer [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html). You need to start activity using Context.startActivity().

Comment: @SurenderKumar my code does actually use that method, don't you see? At first I thought there would be some static method of Context class but not any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the Android version are you trying to implement it on. I faced similar issue before when I was testing on Android 6.0.
I had to manually go to the app permission and switch on the permission for the same.

Alternately you can check the below link.
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

This will help you to check if the user has granted permission for the app.

Hope this helps you. Have a Nice day!!

Comment: The device was tested against has API level of 19, is that OK?

Comment: I have tried you code and it worked fine in API level 19. You can try to clean project and rebuild. Let me know what you get after doing it.

Comment: great, cleaning and rebuilding it works. As before I put the line of <uses-permission> at the wrong place and after corrected it, it might still run the old build. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

***Try Adding both of the permissions.***.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />`

I have faced a similar issue...Resolved by adding both of the permission..

Answer (score 0):

if your are using android M then need to check runtime permission, because in android M can remove permission.

Comment: could you put more effort in your answer because I don't quite understand some things here such as about android M. Also I don't understand why we need to check the permission here, if it's some kind of permission set by the user, I can turn that permission on via the Phone OS and then run my app. What I want here is a simple running app, I don't really want to look into advanced code at this time. Thank you.